# Mischung von Infinitiven, ohne und mit "zu"

Tags: sentence-structure

Ich habe noch eine Frage über einen Satz von Kafka (über denselben Satz habe ich schon eine Frage gestellt, aber das hier ist eine neue):

> Deshalb bleibt doch der beste Rat, alles hinzunehmen, als schwere
> Masse sich verhalten und fühle man sich selbst fortgeblasen, keinen
> unnötigen Schritt sich ablocken lassen, den anderen mit
> Tierblick anschaun, keine Reue fühlen, kurz, das, was vom Leben als
> Gespenst noch übrig ist, mit eigener Hand niederdrücken, d. h., die
> letzte grabmäßige Ruhe noch vermehren und nichts außer ihr mehr
> bestehen lassen.

Die Struktur dieses Satzes ist ein Hauptsatz, auf den eine Reihe Nebensätze folgt, fast alle im Infinitiv, von denen jeder einen Teil des besten Rates beschreibt. Das Verwirrende ist, dass sich der erste Nebensatz ("alles hinzunehmen") um einen Infinitiv mit "zu" handelt, während "zu" den folgenden Infinitiven fehlt. Ich hätte gedacht, alles soll sozusagen parallel laufen, d. h., Kafka könnte, wenn ich recht verstehe, entweder "zu" oder kein "zu" auswählen, aber beide nicht mischen. Aber ich muss irgendwie falsch liegen. Vielleicht kann jemand für mich das Ganze erklären.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zunächst: Aufzählungen und Reihungen können alles mögliche enthalten (das ist übrigens in jeder Sprache, die ich kenne, so), man ist, zumindestens von der Grammatik her, nicht daran gebunden, dass die Elemente einer Aufzählung alle denselben Typ haben, solange der Typ zur Semantik (und Grammatik) der Aufzählung passt (so könnte in der Aufzählung im Beispiel zur Not z.B. einfach das Substantiv "Stoismus" vorkommen).

Berühmtes Beispiel, nur zwei Elemente (zwar ein Zeugma, aber grammatisch OK):

> Ich heiße Heinz Erhard und Sie herzlich willkommen

Zu Kafkas Gunsten nehmen wir an, dass er das nicht einfach so hingeschrieben, sondern sich etwas dabei gedacht hat. Wir haben es in deinem Beispiel also mit einer Aufzählung zu tun, die erweiterte und einfache Infinitive enthält. Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden?

Der erweiterte Infinitiv beschreibt einfach eine Tätigkeit, während der einfache Infinitiv im Deutschen auch Imperativcharakter haben kann (und das hat er hier) - Man könnte den Satz also auch so schreiben, um diesen Imperativcharakter stärker zu verdeutlichen:

> Deshalb bleibt doch der beste Rat, alles hinzunehmen:
>
> - als schwere Masse sich verhalten!
> - Keinen unnötigen Schritt sich ablocken lassen!
> - Den anderen mit Tierblick anschaun!
> - Keine Reue fühlen...

Semantisch ist der Satz also als *generelle Verhaltensbeschreibung* (der erweiterte Infinitiv) mit einer Liste von *Detailanweisungen*, die zu diesem Ziel führen (die einfachen Infinitive) zu verstehen.

Warum man als Muttersprachler den Satz - genau so - auf Anhieb versteht, kann ich leider nur mit "Sprachgefühl" erklären, und verstehe sehr gut, dass jemand, der kein Muttersprachler ist, hier seine Probleme haben kann.

Comment: Danke, gute Erklärung.